# Can I get Android intent extra data for whole application

Tags: android

Suppose I have 5 activities in my android project. When I click a button in activity 1 and I insert an extra data and is carried to activity 2 in the following form.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);  
intent.putExtra("MY_KEY", "MY_DATA_FOR_WHOLE_APP");  
startActivity(intent);
```

In this way, I can use MY_KEY data only in activity 2. But I want to use this data in other activites(2,3,4,5). Are there any way to get this except from SharedPreferences and database.

Answer (score 0):

Activity1

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);  
intent.putExtra("MY_KEY", "MY_DATA_FOR_WHOLE_APP");  
startActivity(intent);
```

Activity2

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity3.class);  
intent.putExtra("MY_KEY", getIntent().getStringExtra("MY_KEY"));  
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a 'helper' class which can be factory for your intents like the following :

```
import android.content.Intent;

public class IntentHelper {

   public static final Intent createYourIntent(Intent src) {
      return new Intent("YourIntent").addCategory("YourCategory").putExtras(src);
   }
}
```

This will be the factory for all your Intents. Every time you need a new Intent, create a static factory method in IntentHelper. You can create a new intent like this:

```
IntentHelper.createYourIntent(getIntent());
```

In your activity, When you want to save some data in a session (same as SharedPreferences) just use the following:

```
IntentHelper.createYourIntent(getIntent()).putExtra("YOUR_FIELD_NAME", fieldValueToSave);
```

And send this Intent. In the target Activity your field will be available as:

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("YOUR_FIELD_NAME");
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a data class

```
public class Data {
private String name;
private static Data instance = null;

public static getInstance(){
if(instance!=null){
return instance;
}else{
instance = new Data();
return instance;
}
}

public void getName(){
return name;
}
public void setName(String name){
this.name = name
}
}
```

Access it in any activity,fragment

```
Data.getInstance().setName("John");
String name = Data.getInstance().getName();
```